# wp_kses_allowed_html filter not working for all tags

Tags: wordpress, svg, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF textarea field on menu items with SVG code in it.

ACF runs this input through wp_kses(), so I am adding this filter to allow the tags in my SVG code to pass.

```
function acf_add_allowed_svg_tag( $tags, $context ) {
    if ( $context === 'acf' ) {
        $tags['svg']  = array(
            'xmlns'             => true,
            'width'         => true,
            'height'        => true,
            'preserveAspectRatio'   => true,
            'fill'              => true,
            'viewbox'               => true,
            'role'              => true,
            'aria-hidden'           => true,
            'focusable'             => true,
        );
        $tags['path'] = array(
            'd'    => true,
            'fill' => true,
        );
        $tags['g'] = [
            'clip-path' => true
        ];
        $tags['linearGradient'] = [
            'id' => true,
            'x1' => true,
            'x2' => true,
            'y1' => true,
            'y2' => true,
            'gradientUnits' => true,
        ];
        $tags['clipPath'] = [
            'id' => true,
        ];
        $tags['stop'] = [
            'stop-color' => true,
            'offset' => true
        ];
        // Others removed for brevity
    }
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'acf_add_allowed_svg_tag', 10, 2 );
```

This is working for svg, path, stop, g, another tags. But it is still stripping out two tags: **linearGradient** and **clipPath**. The common factor here is that these both have compound names, so I'm hypothesizing this is related to why.

Input:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 34 34">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_933_5136)">
        <path fill="url(#paint0_linear_933_5136)" d="M13.7284 12.7318V15.0964H19.5401L16.8197 20.5518V18.1873H11.008L13.7284 12.7318ZM16.8197 -0.358154L6 21.2782H13.7284V33.6418L24.5481 12.0055H16.8197V-0.358154Z" />
    </g>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_933_5136" x1="6" x2="23.4121" y1="4.81576" y2="4.1452" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="#FFAA30" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCCF32" />
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="clip0_933_5136">
            <rect width="34" height="34" fill="#fff" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Output

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 34 34">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_933_5136)">
        <path fill="url(#paint0_linear_933_5136)" d="M13.7284 12.7318V15.0964H19.5401L16.8197 20.5518V18.1873H11.008L13.7284 12.7318ZM16.8197 -0.358154L6 21.2782H13.7284V33.6418L24.5481 12.0055H16.8197V-0.358154Z" />
    </g>
    <defs>
            <stop stop-color="#FFAA30" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCCF32" />
            <rect width="34" height="34" fill="#fff" />
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution: change the tag names to lowercase in the filter function. e.g.  `$tags['lineargradient']`